# Center Button horizontally doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

hy!

I want to center my button horizontally, but this never work.

My Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/minage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"  />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ml_minage_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:padding="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/ml_minage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        style="@style/NFFSeek"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myseekbar"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/maxage" 
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ml_maxage_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/ml_maxage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/NFFSeek"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myseekbar" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ml_distance_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/ml_distance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/NFFSeek"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myseekbar" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gender"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@drawable/rbon" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ml_female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/rbselector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/rb_female"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="42dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ml_male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rb_male"
            android:button="@drawable/rbselector"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="42dp"
            />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ml_stbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Flirt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this xml doesn't fit the button in the middle please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `RelativeLayout` does not span the width of the page, it's width is `wrap_content`. The button is centered in the `RelativeLayout`, but that layout is only as wide as the button, and is mashed up against the left side of the screen.

Make the inner `RelativeLayout`'s width as `match_parent`.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ml_stbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Flirt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't speaking directly to your question, but your view hierarchy is too complicated.  I suggest you replace all of the `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` elements with a single `RelativeLayout` that spans the whole thing.